# Using `chan pending output` instead of writable fileevent

Tags: sockets, tcl

Yo, I've written a server with a simple protocol: the client sends a line, the server sends a line back in response, repeat. To prevent a client from filling Tcl's output buffer by sending lots of lines but not accepting data back, can I just check `chan pending output` instead of using the writable fileevent?

```
proc respond {stream msg} {
    if {[chan pending output $stream] <= 1024} {
        puts $stream $msg
    } else {
        #close $stream
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For output, [`chan pending output`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.htm#M28) will correctly describe the number of bytes waiting in the output queue. Normally, that value will be bounded by the `-buffersize` value that you `chan configure` (or `fconfigure`) it to have.

That value will only be exceeded when the channel is non-blocking; with a blocking channel, when the value would go over it, instead there's a blocking write to the underlying device (socket, pipe, file, serial line, whatever) so by the time you could see that it went over, it's back under the limit again.

But if you're using non-blocking channels, you really should use `chan event` (or `fileevent`). Luckily for the actual writes, Tcl will actually do this for you automatically; the single most useful thing you could want from a writable event is already there. In practice, the most common *actual* use of a writable event is in detecting when an async socket connection becomes ready for service.

So what you are doing will work, but you'll have to **think carefully about what to do if the output buffer is “getting full”**; the idea that a message can need to be delayed is a place where a simple abstraction tends to become leaky. With 8.6's coroutines, you could (probably) do a transparent suspend or something like that, but getting that sort of thing right can take a little thought. (For example, a GUI client might need to show a busy indicator and put things into a state where the user can't enter more requests.)